# Ubuntu server - cannot set static ip

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 16.04

I have set local ubuntu 16.04 server yesterday. I configurated static IP and everything was good. I was able to connect to the server. Today I travelled to city, where i stydy. The server couldnt work becouse of diffrent router settings.

For the last few hours im trying to make it work again. My base system is Windows 10, then I have linux mint 17.3 on virtual machine. On linux i have ubuntu server. In both cases im using virtualbox to host VM's.

Output of ipconfig in Windows:

```
IPv4 Address 192.168.1.10
Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway 192.168.1.1
```

I have two network adapters connected to ubuntu: Host-only and NAT.[Host-only settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnncb.png)

Configuration of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp0s3
address 192.168.1.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Ifconfig for enp0s3 show me:

```
inet addr: 192.168.1.20
```

Ubuntu server has internet connection(i can ping google.com) but i cant connect to local server.
Would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing the NAT adapter to a network bridge adapter. NAT means it is essentially using the IP of your host, which in this case is 192.168.1.10. From there, Virtualbox will act as a router.

Setting it to network bridge adapter will connect the virtual machine to your "real" network.

Comment: Thanks for quick anserw. Changing the second adapter to bridge or even disabling it doesnt make any diffrence. Can you advise me how should i configure my windows network adapter(ones that uses linux mint)? Atm i configured them as nat and host-only

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your virtual machines are setup. Are you saying that you are two different physical machines? One with a Mint VM and one with an Ubuntu Server VM?

Comment: I have one physical machine. Windows hosts linux, linux hosts ubuntu

Comment: Why are you using a VM inside of a VM?

Comment: Because i set mint for my my colleague projects. Then i was force to set another machine to cooperete with mint

Comment: Can I set ubuntu on windows?

Comment: You can move the Ubuntu Server VM to Windows, and run it in VirtualBox under Windows instead. It is not recommended to run a VM inside a VM. I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I can tell you the best practices.